# Pandas: get all rows till column exceeds a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below. Think of it like a sequence of actions done by users (denoted by id) and the time taken (in seconds) for the action to complete. The dataframe below is in the ascending order by which the actions were done by the user.

```
    id   action  time_taken
0    1  action1           1
1    1  action2          10
2    1  action3           2
3    1  action4           5
4    2  action4           1
5    2  action1           4
6    2  action2           3
7    2  action3           9
8    2  action5           4
9    2  action4           5
10   2  action5           6
```

I would like to split the dataframe in such a way that each split contains all the rows till an action took more than 4 seconds for each user. I can set a mask and get all rows between 0 and 5 but how do I do this for each user? Each user can have multiple sets of actions where this could have happened.

The output should be like this:

```
   id   action  time_taken
0   1  action1           1
1   1  action2          10

   id   action  time_taken
0   1  action3           2
1   1  action4           5

   id   action  time_taken
0   2  action4           1
1   2  action1           4
2   2  action2           3
3   2  action3           9

   id   action  time_taken
0   2  action5           4
1   2  action4           5

   id   action  time_taken
0   2  action5           6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = (df["time_taken"] > 4).shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0)
for _, g in df.groupby(["id", m]):
    print(g)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
   id   action  time_taken
0   1  action1           1
1   1  action2          10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id   action  time_taken
2   1  action3           2
3   1  action4           5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id   action  time_taken
4   2  action4           1
5   2  action1           4
6   2  action2           3
7   2  action3           9
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id   action  time_taken
8   2  action5           4
9   2  action4           5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    id   action  time_taken
10   2  action5           6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```